# Keep getting permissions error gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, circleci, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to integrate CircleCi with gcloud Kubernetes engine.

1. I created a service account with Kubernetes Engine Developer and Storage Admin roles.
2. Created CircleCi yaml file and configured CI.

Part of my yaml file includes:

```
docker:
            - image: google/cloud-sdk
        environment:
            - PROJECT_NAME: 'my-project'
            - GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID: 'my-project-112233'
            - GOOGLE_COMPUTE_ZONE: 'us-central1-a'
            - GOOGLE_CLUSTER_NAME: 'my-project-bed'
        steps:
            - checkout
            - run:
                  name: Setup Google Cloud SDK
                  command: |
                      apt-get install -qq -y gettext
                      echo $GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY > ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
                      gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
                      gcloud --quiet config set project ${GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID}
                      gcloud --quiet config set compute/zone ${GOOGLE_COMPUTE_ZONE}
                      gcloud --quiet container clusters get-credentials ${GOOGLE_CLUSTER_NAME}
```

Everything runs perfectly except that the last command:

```
gcloud --quiet container clusters get-credentials ${GOOGLE_CLUSTER_NAME}
```

It keeps failing with the error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission(s) for "projects/my-project-112233/zones/us-central1-a/clusters/my-project-bed". See https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#gke_service_account_deleted for more info.
```

I tried to give the ci account the role of project owner but I still got that error.

I tried to disable and re-enable the Kubernetes Service but it didn't help.

Any idea how to solve this? I am trying to solve it for 4 days...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it's not the CI Service account but the k8s service account used to manage your GKE cluster, where its email should look like this (Somebody must have deleted it):

```
k8s-service-account@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

[image: sa]

You can re-create it an give it project owner permissions.

[image: recreate]

Comment: I don't have such account. Maybe you refer to this account: "service-448608612002@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com"?

Comment: You need to create it. No not that one.

Comment: Suppose I create it, what do I do with it? Who will use it?

Comment: This will use it `gcloud --quiet container clusters get-credentials ${GOOGLE_CLUSTER_NAME}`

Comment: But I already created a service account with Kubernetes Engine Developer and Storage Admin roles. I use it for the `get-credentials` command and it fails. How creating another account with the same roles will help?

Comment: I removed the account and created it again with the same name and roles. And suddenly it works... gcloud bug.

Comment: What did you try? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 7):

This is an old thread, this is how this issue handled today in case using **cloud build** :

**Granting Cloud Build access to GKE**

To deploy the application in your Kubernetes cluster, Cloud Build needs the Kubernetes Engine Developer Identity and Access Management Role.

**Get Project Number:**

```sh
PROJECT_NUMBER="$(gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT_ID} --format='get(projectNumber)')"
```

**Add IAM Policy bindings:**

```sh
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT_NUMBER} \
    --member=serviceAccount:${PROJECT_NUMBER}@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role=roles/container.developer
```

More info can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/gitops-cloud-build#granting_access_to).

Answer (score 3):

In my case, these 2 steps solved my issue:

1. In the command,

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials my-cluster-1 --zone=asia-south1-a -- 
project=thelab-240901
```

the `--project` should have the **projectID** value, not the project name

2. In the your travis account, go to your project repository -> more options -> settings -> Environment Variables. Now make sure you have only one set of encrypted_iv and encrypted_key environment variables as follows:

[image]

If you have encrypted different service accounts (json key files), this could add more than one set of encrypted_iv and encrypted_key environment variables. So, delete all those variables and freshly create the encrypted keys, may be by using `travis encrypt-file --pro yourServiceAccountJSONFile.json --add`

Answer (score 2):

The details of the above mentioned errors are explained in [this help center](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#gke_service_account_deleted) article.

To add the Kubernetes Engine Service account (if you don't have it), please run the following command, in order to properly recreate the Kubernetes Service Account with the "Kubernetes Engine Service Agent" role,

```
gcloud services enable container.googleapis.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : gcloud init

Step 2 : Select [2] Create a new configuration

Step 3 : Enter configuration name. Names start with a lower case letter and 
contain only lower case letters a-z, digits 0-9, and hyphens '-':  kubernetes-service-account

Step 4 : Choose the account you would like to use to perform operations for 
this configuration:[2] Log in with a new account

Step 5 : Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Step 6 : Copy paste the link to brwoser and login with the ID which is used to create your google Cloud Account

Step 7 : Copy the verification code provided by google after login and paste it in to the console.

Step 8 : Pick cloud project to use:

Step 9: Do you want to configure a default Compute Region and Zone? (Y/n)?  y

Step 10 : Please enter numeric choice or text value (must exactly match list item):  8

Your Google Cloud SDK is configured and ready to use!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem using gcloud with my main owner account (!)

What fixed it was including `--zone` and `--project` params in the command to get the kubectl credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error. The issue was that I had already configuered gloud with a google account and I was trying to connect to a cluster I created on a different google account.

**Solution** : Just reset the gcloud configurations and add the new google account.

Do :

```
gcloud init
```

and follow the steps you see in terminal to reset and add the new account.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue with different scenarios, Listing it down below hope it will help someone.

```
1. If you did a fresh installation of google-cloud-sdk then you must login 
with gcloud using the below command.

gcloud auth login

The above command will open ur browser and ask for login with your GCP account.
```

```
2. Sometimes provisioning is not reflected. Hence i revoke my provision and granted access (In this case my role is Owner) again. Then it worked.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when trying to connect to my newly created cluster:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <foo-cluster> --zone europe-central2-a --project <foo-project>
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission(s) for "projects/foo-project/zones/europe-central2-a/clusters/foo-cluster".
```

I tried a few things:

1. I enabled Kuberentes API - no success
2. I added a key to service account and loged in using downloaded key:

   ```
   gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=<path-to-the-downloaded-json-file>/foo-project-xxxx.json
   Activated service account credentials for: [xxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com]
   ```
3. I run:

   ```
   gcloud components update
   ```
4. However, I had a problem retriving data, all kubectl command were giving TLS handshake timeout, for example: `kubectl get namespace` was giving an error:

   ```
       Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
   ```
5. This is when I tried again:

   ```
   gcloud container clusters get-credentials <foo-cluster> --zone europe-central2-a --project <foo-project>
   ```

and it worked

```
    Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
    kubeconfig entry generated for foo-project.
```